# Process count on remote machines on AWS

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, process, amazon-ec2, count

I am designing an Auto Scaling system for my application which runs on Amazon EC2 instances. The application reads messages from SQS and processes them.

The Auto Scaling system will monitor two things:

1. The number of messages in the SQS,
2. The total number of processes running on all EC2 machines.

For example, if the number of messages in SQS exceeds 3000 I want the system to autoscale, create a new EC2 instance, deploy code on it and whenever the number of messages goes below 2000 i want the system to terminate an EC2 instance.

I am doing this with Ruby and capistrano.
My question is:

I am unable to find a method to determine number of processes running on all EC2 machines and save the number inside a variable. Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to utilize cron and CloudWatch API to push the numbers manually to CloudWatch as a part of auto-scaling-group policy. By numbers I mean the number of processes from each instance `ps aux | grep your_process | wc -l`

CloudWatch will let you set alarm for that manual metric aggregated by SUM of the nr of processes across either all running instances or by auto-scaling-group.

Something to let you get started:

Pushing RAM Memory metrics manually:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts-perl.html

One more:
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/05/amazon-cloudwatch-user-defined-metrics.html

For memory it looks simple, as amazon already provides scripts for this. For processes you might need to dig in these scripts or read the official API docs

### EDIT:

If you are now worried about single-point-of-failure in the watching system and you have a list of servers it might be preferred to examine them in parallel from a remote server:

```
rm ~/count.log

# SSH in parallel
for ROW in `cat ~/ListofIP.txt`
do
    IP=`echo ${ROW} | sed 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`
    ssh -i /path/to/keyfile root@${IP} "ps -ef | grep process_name.rb | grep -v grep | wc -l" >> ~/count.log &
done

# Wait for totals
while [ ! `wc -l ~/ListofIP.txt` -eq `wc -l ~/count.log` ]
do
  wait 1
done

# Sum up numbers from ~/count.log
# Push TO CloudWatch
```

Comment: +1. I'll just add that you can execute ps remotely from the monitoring instance (via rsh) so you don't have to change the existing instances in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. iGilli, Were you talking about this:  count = count+ `ssh #{@user}@#{server} ps -ef | grep <process_name>.rb | grep -v grep | wc -l``. I have the IP addresses of all the ec2 instanes running inside the system. Do you see any problem in the approach?

Comment: It depends how critical is that monitoring. What if the remote server (the one you rsh from) dies? It's single point of failure. But if you prefer not updating your environment that's the way to go so please see my updated answer

Comment: @kyser If this answer resolved your question, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  This helps site users quickly see that your question has been resolved, and  rewards you and the answerer a small amount of reputation.